# Best method for live image acquisition and processing in parallel (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I am new to realtime applications and the image acquisition toolbox and I need to run 5 cameras in parallel with realtime image processing in MATLAB. 
I want to use the 5 cameras in parallel but I am aware that I cannot capture the images at the exact same time. What would be the best method to capture the images as "close as possible" to synchronous capture? Using `getsnapshot` in a loop is too slow for me (I want to reach at least some fps).

The next question I have is about the structure of the realtime application in total. What would be the best way to structure the image acquisition and processing? The images of the 5 cameras will be merged together after some steps of processing so I want to show one live image in the end. This whole process works for a "one shot mode", this means that the images are captured manually, then loaded manually by one processing script after the other. 
I want to make this whole real-time pipeline as fast as possible, by using the multiple cores of my CPU or Cuda cores for example.

I am sorry for my rather unspecific questions, but I hope that someone can give me at least a hint of which method would be fitting for me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: i dont think matlab is the tool you want to use for this application.

Comment: Hints: don't use `getsnapshot` in a loop, use callback function instead (like `vid.TriggerFcn = @imaqcallback`). Do all the heavy computations in MEX files of DLLs. Reduce the fps as much as you can.